# Is it possible to find acoustic amplitude at a certain frequency if you are given dBA?

Tags: acoustics

I was wondering how one would find the acoustic amplitude of a sound wave if you knew the dBA value of that sound wave?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Acoustics , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting , http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-soundlevel.htm